# Can you create a fangate on Facebook's mobile?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-page

Just like you can create a fangate to get people to like 1st, can we do the same on Facebook mobile?  Don't believe I see that option.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the Graph API to query the user's "me/likes" to see if your page is on that list.  Then either show the "Like me now to see the good stuff" page, or the "Ok, you've liked me, now you're cool" page.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Tabs don't work on mobile.